# python loop over subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, database

I want to do some data research about student's result in their final examination
on http://diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N6LT.png)
In this page you need to insert your "SoBaoDanh" to search your point at you final test

For example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvdix.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crCuJ.png)
"SoBaoDanh" start form 02000001 to 02089275
So how I can get hole of that result
My code I wrote like this

```
import subprocess    
i = 2000001
    while i < 2089275:  
        result = subprocess.check_output([print("'curl - F" + '"SoBaoDanh=0'+ str(i+1) +'"' + "diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/Home/Show'")])
        print(result)
    i +=1
```

Comment: Your `i += 1` is outside the while loop, so it will iterate endlessly. Still, you should tell us what kind of error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `curl` using `subprocess`, use the `requests` library to make http requests like so

```
import requests as r
for i in range(2000001, 2089275):
   res = r.post("http://diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/Home/Show", data={"SoBaoDanh": "0"+str(i)}) 
   print(res.content)
```

Since the result is an HTML document, you could use an HTML parser like [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to further filter the result stored in `res.content` to get only the part that you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for help me solve this problem.